# Верстка сайта с несколькими блоками для ссылок

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Нужно переместить блок "Бла, бла"(div), вниз под первые три блока. Как это сделать?
И также если не трудно, укажите на другие ошибки в коде <3
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}

.container-fluid {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #B8C9F1;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 10%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container-fluid h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.container, .one-column {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.one, .two, .three {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 28%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.four, .five, .six {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="url" content="https://crowley45.github.io">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Links for layout designer</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Полезные ссылки для&nbsp;верстальщика</h1>
        <p>Различные ресурсы, сайты и сервисы, которые&nbsp;помогут&nbsp;в&nbsp;работе</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="one-column">
            <div class="one">
                <p class="h1">Шрифты</p>
                <ol>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="fonts.google.com">Google Fonts</a> - Самый большой пак шрифтов от Google</li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="app.typeanything.io">Type Anything</a> - Калькулятор параметров текста + генератор CSS-кода</li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="fontstorage.com/tools">Font Storage</a> - Расширение для простого подключения шрифтов</li>
                <ol>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                <p class="h1">Графика</p>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="tinypng.com">TinyPNG</a> - Сжатие изображений</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="three">
                <p class="h1">Валидация</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two-column">
            <div class="four">
                <p class="h1">Бла, бла</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы блоки, которые не вмещаются, переносились добавьте flex-wrap: wrap

По поводу ошибок, оч странно давать класс h1 для тега p, если логичнее просто использовать тег h1

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}

.container-fluid {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #B8C9F1;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 10%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container-fluid h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.container, .one-column, .two-column {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.one, .two, .three {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 28%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.four, .five, .six {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="url" content="https://crowley45.github.io">
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Links for layout designer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Полезные ссылки для&nbsp;верстальщика</h1>
    <p>Различные ресурсы, сайты и сервисы, которые&nbsp;помогут&nbsp;в&nbsp;работе</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="one-column">
      <div class="one">
        <p class="h1">Шрифты</p>
        <ol>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="fonts.google.com">Google Fonts</a> - Самый большой пак шрифтов от Google</li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="app.typeanything.io">Type Anything</a> - Калькулятор параметров текста + генератор CSS-кода</li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="fontstorage.com/tools">Font Storage</a> - Расширение для простого подключения шрифтов</li>
          <ol>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
        <p class="h1">Графика</p>
        <ol>
          <li><a href="tinypng.com">TinyPNG</a> - Сжатие изображений</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="three">
        <p class="h1">Валидация</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="two-column">
      <div class="four">
        <p class="h1">Бла, бла</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, про тэг <p> с классом "h1", это класс из bootstrap. Если везде использовать тэг заголовка первого уровня h1 - валидаторы ругаются

Answer (score 0):

```css
.b-links {
   display: flex;
   width: 80vw;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   margin: auto;
   justify-content: center;

}

.b-links-element{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: 400px;
   min-height: 100px;
   height: auto;
   background-color: bisque;
   margin-right: 2vw;
   margin-top: 2vh;

}
```

```html
      <section class="b-links">
         <div class="b-links-element">
            <h1>Заголовок H1</h1>
            <a href="">Ссылка 1</a>
            <a href="">Ссылка 2</a>
         </div>
         <div class="b-links-element">22</div>
         <div class="b-links-element">333</div>
         <div class="b-links-element">444</div>
         <div class="b-links-element">55</div>
         <div class="b-links-element">666</div>
      </section>
```

[Неплохая шпаргалка по Flex вёрстке](https://itchief.ru/html-and-css/flexbox)